# Load Multiple images using AsyncImageLoader iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, image-caching

I'm trying to load  Multiple images by using AsyncImageLoader ,
I'm use the following code

The first image ..

```
[[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader]loadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXXX1.png"] target:self success:@selector(imageLoaded:) failure:nil];
```

The next one ..

```
[[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader]loadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://XXXX2.png"] target:self success:@selector(imageLoaded:) failure:nil];


-(void)imageLoaded:(UIImage*)ParamImage  
{  
        myImage.image=ParamImage;  
}
```

The problem that **i can't find a way like tag number or another way to differentiate between images** , i mean **how can i know which image is finished loading when the method imageLoaded: called**

Note: Here are the link of AsyncImageView blog
https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView
Any idea ..

Comment: To use `AsyncImageView` you just need to set `[myImage setURL:YOURURL];` the job is done, `AsyncImageView` knows that `myImage` is the imageView to set the image for.

Comment: @iphonic thanks for your comment , but im using AsyncImageView to load the Thumb image while [AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] load the real big image ... 
i do not want to load the big image using AsyncImageView because the screen will remind empty until the full image (big one) finish loading ... is that make sense